# How I can display some category on page load with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have list of items like

```
<div class="cat1">Item 1</div>
<div class="cat2">Item 1</div>
<div class="cat3">Item 1</div>
<div class="cat2">Item 1</div>
<div class="cat3">Item 1</div>
```

How I can display only "cat3" on page load with jquery?

Comment: start with all category hidden, the use http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

First set all `div`'s display `none` and than in `document ready` display whatever class you want to

```
<div class="cat1" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>
<div class="cat2" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>
<div class="cat3" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>
<div class="cat2" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>
<div class="cat3" style="display:none;">Item 1</div>



$(document).ready(function(){

$(".cat3").show();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("div[class^='cat']").hide()
  $(".cat3").show();

});
```

first line It will hide all the divs starting with 'Cat'

second line it will show the div having class cat3

Comment: using your code it will hide only after DOM is ready and visible

Comment: Yep I agree ,The question is asked under Jquery tag. That's the reason I have posted this answer